# Convert an .xlsx file to PDF in Google Colab

Tags: excel, pdf, google-colaboratory, save-as

I can't find a way to automatically convert a bunch of xlsx files to pdf, using a Colab environment.

I use openpyxl to generate hundreds of different excel files, format some cells, delete some rows and columns, but it seems there is no way to convert these hundreds of files to a pdf format.

I made some research on google, and it couldn't find anything that could work.

I want to stay on Colab because this job is for a person who is not technical so I want to keep things as simple as possible.

Thank you.